# multiple with with closure in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to filter data first closure is for attachment and second closure for AdminAttachment

```
   $data = UserSalary::with(['userData','Attachments' => function($query) use($id) {
        $query->where('type', 3);
        $query->where('application_id',$id);
      }])->with(['AdminAttachments' => function($queryadminattachement) use($id) {
        $queryadminattachement->where('type', 3);
        $queryadminattachement->where('application_id',$id);
      }])->find($id);
```

but now i'm getting only Attachment data but AdminAttachment is blank but in my database data is there so it must return datas from both the attachment because search criteria is also same.
Any solution please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Documentation has a section [Eager Loading Multiple Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

> Sometimes you may need to eager load several different relationships in a single operation. To do so, just pass additional arguments to the with method:

```php
$books = App\Book::with(['author', 'publisher'])->get();
```

So dont call `with` method twice, just add new array value.

Comment: But i want to filter data that's why i was using closure

Comment: @user3653474 my answer was not about using or not closure. U called `with` twice. Just call it once

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $data = UserSalary::with(['userData','Attachments','AdminAttachments'])
 
 ->where(function($handle) use($id){
    $handle->whereHas('Attachments',function($query) use($id) {
       $query->where('type', 3);
       $query->where('application_id',$id);
    })
    ->whereHas('AdminAttachments',function($queryadminattachement) use($id) {
       $queryadminattachement->where('type', 3);
       $queryadminattachement->where('application_id',$id);
    });
 })

->find($id);
```

Thanks